# How to save a GraphicsRow output?

Tags: plotting

I need to save the result of GraphicsRow command as a pdf or jpg file.  Something like `GraphicsRow[{plt1,plt2,plt3}] -> pdf`.

On clicking on the image there is not a "Save Graphics as" option that one finds on a Plot output.

In the end, I need to add arrows and annotations to the whole output and save it as a single jpg or pdf file. I can add stuff but I can't get the output saved unless I issue the command `Export["test.pdf", %]`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can `Rasterize` your graphics and work with the result...

Comment: `Export["thePlotsThicken.png", GraphicsRow[{plt1, plt2, plt3}]]` should work. Or `plots = GraphicsRow[{plt1, plt2, plt3}]]` followed by an `Export`.

Comment: You could select the cell the containing your graphics grid and then select the File > Save Selection As ... menu item. You will then get a dialog that will let you save your grid as a PDF.

Comment: @m_goldberg - Many many thanks.  It was exactly what I needed it.

Comment: You can also try using `FullGraphics` on the output, which should give you the context menu. Do note that it can throw a [few surprises](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4526/245)

Comment: The option will also show up on the right-click menu when the option `ContentSelectable -> False` is set for the `GraphicsRow` (or whatever multi-part graphic it might be). I often set this when I make a lot of graphics, partly because I don't usually want the programmatically-generated contents to be changed and partly to make it easier to export them via this menu (which I find is quicker than using the main menu).

Answer (score 21):

The comments already solve the problem, in particular by using the `File` menu or `Export`. But there is also a way to get the usual behavior back that you expect for single `Plot` output, i.e., a **contextual menu appearing when the graphic is selected**. It just has to be selected in the "right way."

Create the plots, and then press the **back arrow** to bring the cursor right behind the graphics row out put:

```
{plt1, plt2, plt3} = Table[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, Pi}], {a, 0, 2}];
GraphicsRow[{plt1, plt2, plt3}]
```

[image: cursor]

The vertical line on the right is the cursor. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + back arrow to select the graphic:

[image: highlight]

As you can see, the orange highlighting around the graphic appears, instead of a *gray* box. Now **right click on the orange border** (not the graphic because that will again switch to the gray box):

[image: menu]

And there's the contextual menu you were looking for!

**Edit**

Another way of getting the orange box on whose border you want to right-click is this:

First click on the graphics row to get the gray box, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (the shortcut for `Extend Selection`) repeatedly until the whole output is highlighted in orange as in the above screen shot.