# Ticks in v10 - a bug or undocumented change

Tags: plotting, bugs, ticks

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.4**

---

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860400/exponential-form-of-tick-marks-for-log-plot-in-mathematica) @Heike provides this code:

```
ticksfun[xmin_, xmax_] := 
 Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]}, {i, Floor[Log10[xmin]], 
   Ceiling[Log10[xmax]]}]

LogLogPlot[Log[x!], {x, 1, 10^5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
 Ticks -> {ticksfun, ticksfun}]
```

This works perfectly in v9.:
[image]

But in v10, it does not:
[image]

The error is:

```
Tick specification must be a list or a function
```

The help page for `Ticks` looks identical in v10 and v9. So the main question, is this a bug or is there an undocumented change in v10?

Note: `Ticks` in `Plot` seems to work relatively ok in v10.

### Update

Based on the analysis provided by @rcollyer, I did some tests between Mathematica v9 and v10:

```
minmax = {};
ticksfun[xmin_, xmax_] := Module[{i},
   minmax = {xmin, xmax};
   Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]},
    {i, Floor[Log10[xmin]], Ceiling[Log10[xmax]]}]
   ];
minmax2 = {};
ticksfun2[xmin_, xmax_] := Module[{i},
   minmax2 = {xmin, xmax};
   Table[i, {i, Floor[xmin], Ceiling[xmax]}]
   ];
```

Then I run:

```
LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, Ticks -> {ticksfun, ticksfun}]
Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, Ticks -> {ticksfun2, ticksfun2}]
```

The first plot has error, the second is ok, fine, so what does Mathematica v9 return on minmax:

```
In[13]:= minmax
minmax2

Out[13]= {1., 100.}

Out[14]= {-2.08333, 102.083}
```

What does Mathematica v10.4 return on minmax?

```
In[101]:= minmax
minmax2

Out[101]= {-0.511686, 5.11686}

Out[102]= {-5.55556, 105.556}
```

I am not experienced in the internals of Mathematica but all this suggests that there is a change in what the plotting functions are sending to ticks fucntions. And notice the change is not only in `LogLogPlot` but in `Plot` as well.
I think Mathematica should not be passing negative numbers in `LogLogPlot`.

### Update 2

When I tried to implement the solution by @rcollyer, I realized, it is necessary to to further conversions. The solution posted at the bottom creates wrong descriptions of the axis --- the ticks are misplaced. The problem is that the range is supplied in natural logarithm while, we are placing log10 descriptions. At this moment I have something like:

```
ticksnofun[xmin_, xmax_] := Module[{i, xmine, xmaxe, xmin10, xmax10},
   {xmine, xmaxe} = {xmin, xmax};
   {xmin10, xmax10} = (#/Log[10]) & /@ {xmine, xmaxe};
   {xmin10, xmax10} = {Ceiling[xmin10], Floor[xmax10]};
   tcks10 = Table[i, {i, xmin10, xmax10}];
   tckse = (#/Log10[E]) & /@ tcks10;
   Transpose[{tckse, Superscript[10, #] & /@ tcks10}]
   ];
```

I am curious whether this could be written in a "better" Mathematica way (yet keeping it readable)?

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug. Maybe related to the dynamic magic giving me trouble [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4526/245).

Comment: `Plot` doesn't work from either.

Comment: It's not a bug in `Plot` nor `LogLogPlot`. Posting answer now.

Comment: @rcollyer I added the bugs tag because I can't access version 10.4 yet and it definitely doesn't work properly in 10.3.

Comment: @Jens beat me to it. I've added the appropriate bug fix note.

Comment: You're correct. It is not a bug, per se, in the ticks function, but what is being passed to the ticks function has changed, as I noted in my answer. So, the original ticks function must be modified: `LogLogPlot` is now passing scaled values, i.e. they are the `Log` of the range. There is a bug in `LogLogPlot` in that a ticks function is not accepted at all between 10.0 and 10.3. That has been mostly fixed.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks. BTW, what is the scaling of what is passed to the ticks function, is it Log10 or Ln (natural)?

Comment: Natural log, same base, internally, as `LogLogPlot`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The advice below is for 10.4 and above. It appears there is a bug in 10.3 and lower.

---

On the surface, it looks like a bug. But, it is a bug in `ticksfun`. To see why, we need to see what is being passed into it, so we modify it as follows:

```
minmax = {};
ticksfun[xmin_, xmax_] := (minmax = {xmin, xmax}; 
  Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]}, 
   {i, Floor[Log10[xmin]], Ceiling[Log10[xmax]]}])
```

Then,

```
In[30]:= LogLogPlot[Log[x!], {x, 1, 10^5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
  Ticks -> {ticksfun, ticksfun}]; minmax

Out[30]= {-2.30259, 13.8155}
```

So, `ticksfun` is being passed a negative number which is evaluating to a `Complex` number, and the Front End is objecting.

Examining the plot range passed to `ticksfun` shows that `LogLogPlot` (and family) are now passing the scaled (logarithmic) range to the ticks function. So, the `Log10` in `ticksfun` are now redundant. Also, the range is in base `E`, so we need to convert to base 10.

```
Clear[ticksfun2];
ticksfun2[xmin_, xmax_] := Table[
  {i Log[10], Superscript[10, i]}, 
  {i, Floor[xmin/Log[10]], Ceiling[xmax/Log[10]]}
 ]
```

[image]

(**Edit**: previous versions failed to take the base change into account. Fixed.)

Comment: I'd have used `Clip[]` myself...

Comment: Hmm. It should be giving the full range. Give me a sec to make adjustments.

Comment: @J.M. I don't think so. Where would I clip it?

Comment: @rcollyer Still doesn't work for me

Comment: @BlacKow there might be a bug there on early versions of 10. What version are you using?

Comment: @rcollyer 10.0.1.0

Comment: I meant, to impose the "can't be less than 0" condition.

Comment: @J.M. right. But, where? Prior to going into `Log10`? What's the cutoff? If 0, then you feed `Ticks` `Infinity`. So, I think `If` is the appropriate thing here.

Comment: How very odd... `LogLogPlot[Log[x!], {x, 1, 10^5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, Ticks -> {(Echo[{##}]; ticksfunModified[##]) &, ticksfunModified}]`.

Comment: I finally got back to this. I am getting pretty sure there is something wrong (or different) with `LogLogPlot`. I reproduced @rcollyer 's code in Mathematica 9. Just to make everything simpler, I used a different function this time, the update is in the main post.

Comment: @leosenko did you see that note where I said that there is a bug present in 10.0 to 10.3? It is fixed, for some definition of fixed, in 10.4, as long as you're not using pure functions, see JM's note above. :)

Comment: @rcollyer I did, that is what took me so long to reply, I needed to get v10.4. See the update on what is happening in v10.4 vs v9. Mathematica is passing rather different minima and maxima from `LogLogPlot` to ticks functions, in this regard Mathematica v10.0 - 10.3 behaves much like 10.4.

Comment: @leosenko not exactly. `LogLogPlot` is passing the log of the range, i.e. you don't have to perform the log yourself. And, while it is a change, it is arguable if it is a bug.

Comment: @rcollyer I updated your soluton in my question. Can you take a look whether this implementation is ok?

Comment: @leosenko that's moderately embarrassing not doing that conversion. At least I'm in "good" [company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter). I'll take a closer look at the code tonight.

Comment: @leosenko I revised my code. It was a relatively simple change.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks. Unfortunately, I came accross another strange behaviour. Can you please try `LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 100}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticksfun2, ticksfun2}, {None, None}}]` where `ticksfun2` is the updated version you posted. And then try: `LogLogPlot[x^2, {x, 1, 100}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticksfun2, {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000}}, {None, None}}]` . Are you getting different scales on the left and right axes? (As if the left axis accepted the coordinates in natural log and the righ axis accepted coordinates in decimal numbers.

Comment: @leosenko that looks like what happened. I've got a bug report filed. In the meantime, you can use the original `ticksfun` for the right side frame.

Comment: @rcollyer Back to ticks, can you please confirm that `ListLogLogPlot` does not work with custom ticks, to reproduce:`dat = Exp[#] & /@ Table[i, {i, 0, 15, 0.1}];ListLogLogPlot[dat, Ticks -> {ticksfun2, ticksfun2}]` and Mathematica keeps doing something but after 3 minutes, I have given up. Is there any way to escalate the ticks problems?

Comment: @leosenko the ticks issue with `LogLogPlot` has been reported (by me), it is in the system. `ListLogLogPlot` is a different beast, though, and they do not share much in the way of code. So, a quick check shows that `ListLogLogPlot` is sending the un-scaled data which means that the original `ticksfun` works just fine with it. So, to re-iterate, the deviation appears in `LogLogPlot`, not `ListLogLogPlot`.

Comment: @rcollyer When I use `ticksfun` with `ListLogLogPlot`, the ticks seem to be  correctly placed but the `Superscript` is ignored and the numbers are not in $10^i$ format.

Comment: @leosenko you're right. That is "interesting". It is ignoring the labels. Run it with `Clear[ticksfun3];
ticksfun3[xmin_, xmax_] := 
 Block[{res = 
    Table[{i, "a" <> ToString[i]}, {i, Floor[Log10[xmin]], 
      Ceiling[Log10[xmax]]}]},
  Print[res]; res] ` to see what I mean. The labels are ignored in favor of its own labels. Reporting it.

Comment: @leosenko for `ListLogLogPlot` have you considered using `ListPlot` with `ScalingFunctions`?